# Retrieve relationships via LAZY loading or JOIN FETCH?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading, eager-loading

Assume I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  private EntityA a;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  private EntityB b;

  .
  .
  .


  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  private EntityX x;
}
```

All relationships are lazy loaded because in majority of cases they're not needed for business logic. Next, assume there's an endpoint that returns all data for a specific Foo entity by ID. There're two options to retrieve data:

1. Rely on lazy loading which means that X database requests will be made for X relationships. This approach seems fine considering that requests are lightweight and they fetch only 1 row per table. Additionally, its more pleasant for code maintenance.
2. Write a big HQL query that JOIN FETCHes all necessary relationships. This approach performs only one database request and works by a few milliseconds faster than the option above, however, hibernate generates a very big SQL that might have performance issues in specific edge cases and the developer has to maintain a big HQL query.

Are there any best practices around this case? Which approach would be better for this specific scenario?

Comment: If you tend to have  hundreds of entities in the one-to-many relations you must not rely on lazy loading which will most of the time implies hundreds of query.

Comment: You need to take care of the amount of data by your self by creating one or more request or use entity graphs.  A first limitation is that the number of JOIN FETCH is limited by hibernate to avoid huge cartesian product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however, hibernate generates a very big SQL that **might** have performance issues in specific edge cases

I don't quite understand. The word "might" seems to be doing a whole lotta work here. Do you have any actual *evidence* that the SQL Hibernate generates results in poor performance?

Because in general, joining multiple `@ManyToOne` associations is something that the database is able to do *very* efficiently, and is unlikely to cause a problem.

And to be clear "a very big SQL" is not in any way an indicator of poor performance.

Therefore: your option 2 is the recommendation.

Now, on the other hand, problems *do* arise if you join multiple `@OneToMany` associations, and so for that case one might need to consider more exotic solutions, for example, the use of `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`. But that is *not* the case you have exhibited in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Criteria offers another option to accomplish this. You can specify association fetching semantics at runtime using setFetchMode(). Like this:

```
List cats = session.createCriteria(Foo.class)
    .setFetchMode("a", FetchMode.EAGER)
    .setFetchMode("b", FetchMode.EAGER)
    // ...
    .setFetchMode("x", FetchMode.EAGER)
    .list();
```

With this approach you can leave the lazy loading settings in the entities for the majority of use cases. Only for the endpoint where you need to load the fat object with references - use the above code. Hibernate will generate a single query with all joins. Exactly what you wanted in the point 2. but without a hard-coded and error-prone query string.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to separate to 2 method:

```
List<Foo> getById(Long id);

@Query("SELECT foo FROM Foo foo JOIN FETCH...")
List<Foo> getByIdIncludeRef(Long id);
```